# Delegate methods in Objective-C and viewcontroller in Swift. How to call protocols? - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates

I have view controller like in Swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, DraggableViewDelegate {
```

(Type viewcontroller does not conform to protocol 'DraggableviewDelegate')

I knew that I have to take protocol methods from delegate class, but it was a in Objective-C like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "OverlayView.h"

@protocol DraggableViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card;
-(void)cardSwipedRight:(UIView *)card;

@end

@interface DraggableView : UIView

@property (weak) id <DraggableViewDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong)UIPanGestureRecognizer   *panGestureRecognizer;
@property (nonatomic)CGPoint originalPoint;
@property (nonatomic,strong)OverlayView* overlayView;
@property (nonatomic,strong)UILabel* information; 


-(void)leftClickAction;
-(void)rightClickAction;

@end
```

Here the methods are in Objective-C:

```
 -(void)method {}
```

But in Swift it takes:

```
func methodName(){}
```

Comment: So what is wrong if it takes `func methodName(){}` in swift and remember  objective - c and swift are different language so both have different syntaxes you can use it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Apple guide for you

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

And here is great answer how to make bridging header

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/2382237

Answer (score 0):

Writing like a func card...  its taking the delagate methods. like

```
-(void)cardSwipedLeft:(UIView *)card; as
func cardSwipedLeft.....
```

Thanks Doro and Dharmesh Kheni for solution and best tuitorial